# In Coral MIcro API (C++), how to call GetFrame, and pass the resulting image AND the infered bounding box to the server?

Tags: c++, google-coral

I want to add a detection movement model into the code of [camera_streaming_http example](https://github.com/google-coral/coralmicro/tree/main/examples/camera_streaming_http) from the Coral Micro API.

In the example, a function called *`UriHandler`* is created and then passed to the HTTP server using the *`AddUriHandler`* function. Here is the *`UriHandler`* function:

```
HttpServer::Content UriHandler(const char\* uri) {
if (StrEndsWith(uri, "index.shtml") ||
StrEndsWith(uri, "coral_micro_camera.html")) {
return std::string(kIndexFileName);
} else if (StrEndsWith(uri, kCameraStreamUrlPrefix)) {
// \[start-snippet:jpeg\]
std::vector\<uint8_t\> buf(CameraTask::kWidth \* CameraTask::kHeight \*
CameraFormatBpp(CameraFormat::kRgb));
auto fmt = CameraFrameFormat{
CameraFormat::kRgb,       CameraFilterMethod::kBilinear,
CameraRotation::k0,       CameraTask::kWidth,
CameraTask::kHeight,
/*preserve_ratio=*/false, buf.data(),
/*while_balance=*/true};
if (!CameraTask::GetSingleton()-\>GetFrame({fmt})) {
printf("Unable to get frame from camera\\r\\n");
return {};
}

    std::vector<uint8_t> jpeg;
    JpegCompressRgb(buf.data(), fmt.width, fmt.height, /*quality=*/75, &jpeg);
    // [end-snippet:jpeg]
    return jpeg;

}
return {};
}
```

Instead of only returning an image (which here, is simply the image taken by the camera) I also want to return the result of the `tensorflow::GetDetectionResults` function which should use the same frame called in the UriHandler function.

Is it possible to do something like this ? How ?

I am asking this because the `UriHandler` can only return a [HttpServer::Content](https://coral.ai/docs/reference/micro/network/#_CPPv4N10coralmicro10HttpServer7ContentE) which can only one of three types (see the definition).

Thanks a lot

Comment: Is it an option to stuff the bounding box inside a response header? Depends on what the client can handle of course...

Comment: @Botje the "client" in my case is a Javascript code using the fetch function, I think your idea is worth trying, thank you

Comment: Well I don't see any way to add custom headers in the Micro C++ API

Comment: That API is not chiseled in stone. You can trivially copy the files of that http server implementation into your own program and modify it. One such approach would allow you to set the `FS_FILE_FLAGS_HEADER_INCLUDED` flag on the returned "file" and then include the headers with your picture.